# Scala Asynchronous Database Calls

Tags: database, postgresql, scala, asynchronous, slick

I'm currently using Slick 3.x.x which is completely asynchronous in all its calls to the database. Let's say, I have a table that has some sort of versioning. Every time I create a new entry from an already existing entry (i.e. updating a given entry), I have to make sure that I increment the version number.

How can I make sure in this asynchronous world of database communications that I can maintain data integrity? In my case with versioning, I would first do a select for the max version which would give me back a Future and then I use the result of this Future, increment 1 and issue a create command!

It could very well be possible that thread 1 started with select max version and paused for a while, thread 2 catering to a new request could run the select for max version and increment and write the new record in the database. Now thread1 comes back and tries to so the same process, but only to result in the fact that thread1 would overwrite what thread2 wrote in the database.

It could be that I might end up having multiple duplicates because the order in which multiple futures might be run might differ!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The asynchrony with which your application manages its interaction with the database doesn't alter the semantics of database transactions. if you want atomic, consistent sequences of operations, then you want a database transaction. Slick [offers](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/dbio.html?highlight=transactions) a "combinator" called `transactionally` which will force a sequence of operations to run within a database transaction.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the "transactionally". In the documentatin, I could see that there is a warning which goes like this: "Warning:-
Failure is not guaranteed to be atomic at the level of an individual DBIOAction that is wrapped with transactionally, so you should not apply error recovery combinators at that point. An actual database transaction is inly created and committed / rolled back for the outermost transactionally action." I could not make complete sense of it. Could anyone explain?

Comment: suppose you have multiple DBIOActions, lets call them `action1` and `action2`. You might string them together with `action1 andThen action2`. Suppose you did `(action1.transactionally andThen action2).transactionally` nested transaction semantics aren't guaranteed to be supported, so this might be equivalent to just `(action1 andThen action2).transactionally`. so a construct like  `(action1.transactionally.cleanUp(...) andThen action2).transactionally` might fail clean up after rollbacks.  `(action1 andThen action2).transactionally.cleanUp(...)` would catch them, though.

Comment: Say, I have (action1 andThen action2).transactionally produces a version number 2 for a column in a table and another thread that executes the same method that contains my two actions would see 2 or perhaps 3 or even 1 for the version number? Since the result of (action1 andThen action2).transactionally returns a Future, how can I guarantee that the data seen by another Future would be the result of its previous Future?

Comment: one of the transactions is guaranteed to fail if the two executions interfere. that is, if transaction1 reads a 1 then updates to increment that to 2, and transaction2 happens to read between transactions1's read and update so it also reads a 1 and then also tries to update to 2, one of the two transactions will fail. if each execution is wrapped in a future, then one of the futures will complete in a failed state. and then you'll know!

Comment: Ok I get that! So it looks like using transactionally outside of all my actions seems to be the way to go!